# nanosleep() wait for at least 15 ms?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, timing, duration

In order to make a good timing in an emulator, I have to wait for around 50 microseconds.
When I use nanosleep, for example with a duration of 10 microsecs, I measure a delay of 15 millisec ! I use mingw on windows with the following example code :

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec startx, endx;
    struct timespec req={0};
    
    req.tv_sec=0;
    req.tv_nsec=10000; // 10_000 ns = 10 microseconds
    
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startx);
        nanosleep(&req, NULL);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &endx);
        
        if (endx.tv_sec-startx.tv_sec)
            printf("%li microsecs\n",((endx.tv_nsec-startx.tv_nsec)/1000)+1000000);
        else
            printf("%li microsecs\n",(endx.tv_nsec-startx.tv_nsec)/1000);
    }
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

And the result is :

```
12528 microsecs
19495 microsecs
14890 microsecs
14229 microsecs
14657 microsecs
14824 microsecs
14724 microsecs
21074 microsecs
13697 microsecs
13893 microsecs
```

I guess I'm wrong somewhere....
If someone has an idea. I could also avoid the problem with a "do nop while (end-start) < 50usec"...

Thanks.

Comment: **It is hardware and operating-system specific**. Some computers cannot measure time to better than a millisecond. Do you have some [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) in your computer? My recommendation would be to install some Linux distribution, then read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). And you could have *other processes running*. Read a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: If `nanosleep` uses the Win32 `Sleep` function then the default timer resolution 15.6ms. You can attempt to lower it with `timeBeginPeriod` but the lowest you can go is 1ms.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that would be a multi-boot system then, not being hosted by Windows?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Not necessarily. One could install Linux without keeping Windows. BTW, I am using Linux since 1993, Unix since 1985, coding since 1975, and I *never* used Windows.

Comment: @cgyed I used to write emulators for micros. I would get the emulations to run at approximately real time speed simply by having the (awful practice) of a delay loop in the instruction emulation loop, tuned in real time by looking at the general rate of throughput. It wasn't possible to get exact real time anyway, because of the watch and trace and peripheral emulation, and the OS. For example when not tracing, I would refresh the screen display about twice a second (too fast would be meaningless).

Comment: Any kind of delay instruction, like `nanosleep()` can only specify the minimum elapsed time.  So the actual elapsed time will (always) be slightly longer.  How much longer depends on depends on many things, like how often the task scheduler looks at the list of tasks that are ready to execute.

Comment: This may explain the issue you're encountering: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

Comment: @Iridium This one is very interesting too. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/ Been a while since I've visited Bruce. There's always something good to read there, just have to try and avoid falling into the wormhole and reading everything. :)

Answer (score 1):

When I run the posted code through a compiler (gcc) the compiler outputs the following:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:16:57: error: ‘err’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   16 |         if (nanosleep(&req, NULL)) printf("err : %i\n", err);
      |                                                         ^~~
untitled1.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

untitled1.c:18:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__syscall_slong_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
   18 |         printf("%d microsecs %d\n",(endx.tv_nsec-startx.tv_nsec)/1000, endx.tv_sec-startx.tv_sec);
      |                 ~^                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                  |                                              |
      |                  int                                            __syscall_slong_t {aka long int}
      |                 %ld

untitled1.c:18:31: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘__time_t’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
   18 |         printf("%d microsecs %d\n",(endx.tv_nsec-startx.tv_nsec)/1000, endx.tv_sec-startx.tv_sec);
      |                              ~^                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |                                                   |
      |                               int                                                 __time_t {aka long int}
      |                              %ld
Compilation failed.
```

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

to start, suggest casting the result of the call to `time()` to be a `long int`

as to your question:

context switches take time AND the cpu(s) are probably busy with other tasks AND the task scheduler only looks at the list of tasks ready to run periodically , so your request will not be immediately serviced.

to obtain a more accurate timing, do not depend on the OS.  Rather use one of the hardware timers to produce a interrupt event when you want the elapsed time to expire.  Then use an interrupt handler to handle the interrupt event from the hardware timer.

Comment: Thanks for those information. I edited the code to compile against the compilation option. I agree to avoid the OS dependance to this kind of accurate timing. However, I'm suprised of this important gap : 15ms vs 10us, the factor is more or less 1500. Actually, 15ms seems to me huge.

Comment: One major reason for the 15msec interval is because (back in the 'old' days), a CPU clock of 1mhz (or less) was very common.  so only a few cpu cycles would occur in 15msec.
Many many legacy programs depend on the interval.
With today's multi ghz cpus, that interval seems excessively long,  but old systems still need to be supported